# login com sessão php

Tags: php, session, login

Gostaria de quando chegar na página com sessão somente um usuário com certo login entrasse porém da erro quando eu acesso

código php:

```
if($_SESSION['login'] == 'admin')
{
echo "logado";
}
```

Ele dá erro na parte do session no if, como se não tivesse.

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que colocar uma condição para quando entrar ele verificar se a session existe, tente:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
```

provavelmente irá resolver

Comment: era isso mesmo! obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O correto é verificar o isset e depois comparar a string

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == 'admin')
{
   echo "logado";
}
```